# Running ssh command and keeping connection

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to execute a command before accessing a remote terminal

When I enter this command:

`bash
$> ssh user@server.com 'ls'`

The ls command is executed on the remote computer but ssh quits and I cannot continue in my remote session.

Is there a way of keeping the connection? The reason that I am asking this is that I want to create a setup for ssh session without having to modify the remote .bashrc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using process subsitution on the init file of bash. In the example below, I define a function `myfunc`:

```
myfunc () {
   echo "Running myfunc"
}
```

which I transform to a properly-escaped one-liner echoed in the `<(...)` construct for process subsitution for the `--init-file` argument of bash:

```
$ ssh -t localhost 'bash --init-file <( echo "myfunc() { echo \"Running myfunc\" ; }" )  '
Password:
bash-3.2$ myfunc
Running myfunc
bash-3.2$ exit
```

Note that once connected, my `.bashrc` is not sourced but `myfunc` is defined and properly usable in an interactive session.

It might prove a little difficult for more complex bash functions, but it works.

Comment: I need to have access to my .bashrc, so I changed it to: `ssh -t localhost 'bash --init-file <( echo "source ~/.bashrc;myfunc() { echo \"Running myfunc\" ; }" )  '`

Comment: Do you have an idea if it's possible to add this command it the ssh config file? In fact, I would like to run this command each time that I log in to the server through ssh.

Comment: You might be able to do that with `ProxyCommand` in the ssh config.

Comment: I tried without success, but I don't understand the man page very well.

Answer (score 2):

I would force the allocation of a pseudo tty and then run bash after the `ls` command:

```
syzdek@host1$ ssh -t host2.example.com 'ls -l /dev/null;   bash'
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     other          27 Apr  1  2005 /dev/null
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: In fact in my case I cannot do that since my command is for setup. If I run bash, I will lose all setup that I have made.

Comment: Instead of a generic command, can you tell us what specifically you are trying to run?

Comment: I want to create a bash function that will run a netcat on a reverse tunneled port.